# Angular TypeError when the page opens

Tags: html, angular, typescript

In my code, I'm displaying a list of elements on the main page. When you click one of those elements, a side-pannel opens and you are able to see the details of that element. Whenever the page first opens I get the error below. The code doesn't crash or anything, but I don't get why the error keeps appearing. What should I do to fix it?

StickerListComponent.html:167 ;

```
<fuse-sidebar class="sidebar centra details-sidebar fuse-white" name="sticker-preview-sidebar" position="right">
    <sticker-preview  [StickerData]="previewStickerData"></sticker-preview>
</fuse-sidebar>
```

sticker-preview-component html ;

```
<div class="h-100-p" fxLayout="column"  fusePerfectScrollbar>
        <div class="group mt-32">
            <div fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                <header class="purple-fg" style="font-size:18.72px"><strong>Sticker Data:</strong></header>
            </div>
            <p>
                <span id="sticker" contenteditable [textContent]="_stickerData?.StickerData" (input)="onStickerDataChange($event.target.innerHTML)">
                    {{_stickerData?.StickerData}}
                </span>
            </p>           
        </div>
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
            <button mat-button matRipple class="purple-500 fuse-white-fg mr-12" (click)="imageSource()"> Display </button>
    </div> 
    <div>
        <img  [src]="url" *ngIf="hidden" />
    </div>
</div>
```

sticker-preview-component ts:

```
export class StickerPreviewComponent implements OnInit {
    EditIndex: number;
    public _stickerData: IStickerData = {};
    confirmDialogRef: MatDialogRef<FuseConfirmDialogComponent>;
    Filter: IFilter = {};
    hidden = false;
    url;

    

    @Input()
    set StickerData(prm: IStickerData) {
    if (this._stickerData != prm) {
        this._stickerData = prm;
    }
33    this.url = "http://api.labelary.com/v1/printers/8dpmm/labels/4x6/0/" + this._stickerData.StickerData;

}
    get StickerData(): IStickerData {
        return this._stickerData;
    }
 
    dataSource: MatTableDataSource<IStickerData>;
ngOnInit() {
        this._productionService.getStickerDataList(this.Filter)
            .subscribe((response: any) => this._stickerData = response);

    }
    imageSource(): void{
        this.hidden = !this.hidden;
      }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please share whole component code?

Comment: I shared both ts and html

Comment: Whats the difference between the StickerData that you get from `this._productionService.getStickerDataList` and @Input ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems the `_stickerData` is `undefined` at the time when it assigns to the url, try to check whether the `_stickerData` has the proper value and then assign it.

```
if(this._stickerData)
this.url = "http://api.labelary.com/v1/printers/8dpmm/labels/4x6/0/" + this._stickerData.StickerData;
```